# Deploying a NodeJS app with Passenger

Tags: node.js, npm, passenger

I am trying to deploy a NodeJs App : [DemocracyOs](https://github.com/DemocracyOS/democracyos), on apache with [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/).

The Makfile of this project runs **npm** :

```
npm run start
```

The [documentation of Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/nodejs/) requires to enter the target json file `app.js`.

In that case I understand this is [index.js](https://github.com/DemocracyOS/democracyos/blob/master/index.js).

However, when I try to launhc passenger with this file, or to run it directly with

```
node index.js
```

... I get the following error :

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'lib/config'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/raphael/democracyos/index.js:2:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I guess npm does something specific with [package.json](https://github.com/DemocracyOS/democracyos/blob/master/package.json), which defines some kind of mapping :

```
"browser": {
    "lib/config": "lib/config/config"
}
```

How can I get **Passenger** behave like **npm** ?

Comment: Based on this: https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec You should be able to simply move the relevant package into place (not you'll have to keep both the server path and client path valid which is a bit of a mess). However there may be a built-in mechanism to perform this for you, but it's not documented on that page.

Comment: I had the same issue and I ended up using [PM2](https://pm2.io/runtime/) which let me run `pm2 start npm --name "my-app" -- start`. Anyway I'd love to know how to achieve the same with Passenger.